# Enabling builtin Validity fingerprint sensor

Tags: drivers, hp, hardware, 21.04, fingerprint-reader

I have HP Elitebook 8470p with a **Builtin** validity fingerprint sensor. How can I enable this fingerprint sensor ?

> Remember: This is a built-in sensor, and not USB.

---

My info:

- HP Elitebook 8470p
- Vadidlity builtin fingerprint sensor
- Kubuntu 21.04
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.11.0-31-generic
- Fingerprint Device: VFS471

---

And this is the output of `sudo lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
23:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

---

The output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable SoftSailing
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c03 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. HP HD Webcam [Fixed]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `sudo lspci`? There are quite a few models of sensor and guessing which one HP used for your particular notebook would be suboptimal 

Comment: i edited the question, now you can see the output of sudo lspci.

Comment: Hey @Amreessa ! You have formatted the code output as a quote. So, it's difficult for us to read. I suggest you to go through this: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Sorry, I sperated eatch line with <br>

Comment: But why i canot see the fingerprint device ? i think no one of these devices refer to the fingerprint device

Comment: Hey, It is appeared in lsusb ... but how ? it is built in. this is the line in lsusb outpot `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader`

Comment: Correct. Most fingerprint sensors *are* USB devices, though they are internal devices. Based on [this report](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:138a-003c), that device is not compatible with any version of Linux.

Comment: I added the lsusb outpot.